# IOS mobile app test automation on windows

Tags: testing, automated-tests, appium-android, appium-ios, testautomationfx

I have got a freelance project for mobile app test automation.The app is written in react native. I need to run test automation on IOS and android. But I haven't a macbook.Basically, I use appium , Java,Testng to write automation tests on android. But I haven't automated the IOS app.

Is there any way to test and run an IOS emulator and detect elements on the IOS app on windows.

Or Is there any online tools for UI automation on Both android and IOS both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost - you cannot run an iOS emulator on Windows, if you don't have a real device that will make things very complicated. If that is the case then you can check out [this](https://github.com/sickcodes/Docker-OSX) project that allows you to run OSX VM and inside that VM you can start an iOS sim and develop your tests against it - I've never used it for this and I don't know what kind of performance you can expect. If you have an iOS device available you can check out [Appium Studio](https://digital.ai/products/continuous-testing/appium-studio/) - with it you can do iOS automation on Windows, the caveat is you still need to have Apple Developer account to be able to sign WebDriverAgent and I assume your app as well. The third option is the paid one - if you have money to spare you can pay for any of the cloud device farms like [Browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com/) and develop and run tests against their devices, there might be cheaper options than Browserstack if you do some research

Comment: I was trying on BrowserStack.Now what I need to know is if can I ask the developer to add accessibility ids to elements on IOS and Android. And can I run it on BrowserStack without changing Android elements? For APK and IPA same elements can I request for the same name Is it possible? As I know accessibility ID for ios elements are 'name' and for android it's resource id.Anyway there's an option from Browserstack to inspect elements.But it is in Beta.

Comment: You don't have to use the Browserstack beta inspector, you can actually use Appium Desktop as described [here](https://www.browserstack.com/docs/app-automate/appium/integrations/appium-desktop). Of course you can ask the developers to provide the same identifiers in both Android and iOS, but you will have to handle them separately in the code for each platform

Comment: For IOS I have to use Browserstack inspector since I'm not having a Mac??

Comment: I have to pay for the apple developer account?

Comment: You don't need a Mac because you connect to an iOS device on Browserstack cloud that already has WebDriverAgent and Appium server running. You just provide the capabilities to Appium Desktop as described in the article I linked and you should be good to go

Comment: Thanks, I tried on that.Do you have any idea how to locate elements on Hybrid mobile app?? I have no clear idea about how the elements are being created when creating an android or IOS build for a particular app. Think we have a react app, Is that the same way as identifying elements in a native android app?? Can we get the resource id? How it works on IOS app